Angular Material. Value changes in Timeout don't get applied
This might come down to me generally misunderstanding Angular, since I'm just playing around with it currently. I'm trying to display a fake progress-bar using the "angular/material/progress-bar" component. (https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/)
I can display the progress bar like this in "app.component.html":


<mat-progress-bar id="progBar1" mode="determinate" [value]= "progressBarValue" class="visible"></mat-progress-bar>



I can also use the "value" input in "app.component.ts" to set its progress once. If I use setTimeout() or setInterval() however, to delay the change or repeatedly add to the value it doesn't get applied:


import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatProgressBar, MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar'; 

var progressBarValueInternal:number = 1;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Eduardeo-App';
  progressBarValue = progressBarValueInternal;
}

progressBarValueInternal=50;
setTimeout(()=>{console.log("Setting ProgressBar to 75"); progressBarValueInternal=75;}, 5000);



With the above code, the console will print "Setting ProgressBar to 75" but the bar will remain at the initially set 50%. Any ideas, why that might be the case?

All initialisation actions need to happen on ngOnInit hook
Angular component life cycle docs
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatProgressBar, MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Eduardeo-App';
  progressBarValue = 1;
  progressBarValueInternal=50;

  ngOnInit(){
      setTimeout(()=>{
          console.log("Setting ProgressBar to 75"); 
          this.progressBarValueInternal=75;
      }, 5000);
  }
}


Yes! That worked! I knew it had to be something simple, I wasn't getting. Didn't know, what to google for, though ^^ Thanks!
